# Making multiple threads in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I create a for loop which creates multiple threads which can be identifiable. The threads are `Players` in a game and need to communicate with each other. I need to be able to access each player's getters and setters.

Basically, each `Player` has a name attribute and needs to be identifiable. If i do this, I don't see how they are identifiable from one another...

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Player("Player" + (i + 1), (i + 1), (i + 2)));
    }
```

Comment: if you need to start the thread just after declaring t call the start() method as `t.start();` and [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial) would help you, or [these examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616115/Java-Thread-Example)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a `Map` of players, and pass this `Map` to each `Player` so that they can communicate with each other directly (or make the map `static` so that it's visible to all `Player` objects, or whatever)

```
Map<String, Player> players = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
    players.put("Player" + (i + 1), new Player("Player" (i + 1), (i + 1), (i + 2), players));
}
for(Player player : map.values()) {
    new Thread(player).start();
}
```

Another option is to create a class that acts as a message bus that has access to all of the players' setters - if a player wants to send a message to another player then it sends the message to the message bus, which then takes care of calling the appropriate setter method(s)

Comment: You can then make the message bus threaded so that the player doesn't have to block to communicate with the other players.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `numberOfPlayers` then create an array of `Thread`, and populate it inside the loop:

```
Thread[] players = new Thread[numberOfPlayers];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
    players[i] = new Thread(new Player("Player" + (i + 1), (i + 1), (i + 2)));
    // You can start the thread here only
}
```

But if you don't know the numberOfPlayers in advance, while creating the array, you can create an `ArrayList<Thread>` and add each new thread to it:

```
List<Thread> players = new ArrayList<Thread>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
    players.add(new Thread(new Player("Player" + (i + 1), (i + 1), (i + 2))));
}
```